# Did the Justice League poster intentionally use the same style as a graphic novel collection?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league, justice-league-2017, poster-design

[Eaglemoss](https://www.eaglemoss.com/en-gb/comic-heroes/dc-comic-books/) have released [The DC Comics Graphic Novel Collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Comics_Graphic_Novel_Collection) where the combined spines of the hardback comics show the following image:

[image: eaglemoss]

I noticed that the new Justice League poster shows our heroes in remarkably similar poses (minus Cyborg but he does stand quite similar to Green Lantern above):

[image: Justice League]

It looks like the Justice League poster is almost mirroring that of the comics.

**Was this intentional?**

Comment: Well all superheroes have characteristic poses so I guess so

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The poster is an homage to [Alex Ross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_Ross), who has done the artwork for many DC comics, and that one on the comic cover was done by him.  [This article](http://comicbook.com/dc/2017/07/26/justice-league-movie-poster-alex-ross/) shows that there are many comparisons, and confirms that the photographer did base the poster off of his work.

According to Clay Enos, the photographer for the movie poster:

> “I first saw this painting as part of the Ayman Hariri’s Impossible Collection and it inspired me to shoot our gang in the same style,” Enos said, referring to Ross’s painting of the Justice League for the 2005 Justice comic book series seen below and to the DC Comics collection of a billionaire. “I used this exact image as my reference for what became the latest JL poster. I simply had the idea and took the initiative to pay homage to Alex Ross by making a few quick portraits in that distinctive light.”

Comment: Tried to find something like that in your answer but couldn't. Many thanks ;-)